# Sagemaker model inference 'Please provide a model_fn implementation.' errors

Tags: python, scikit-learn, amazon-sagemaker

I am trying to deploy a model from Sagemaker script mode, however every time I try to create an endpoint the logs include mysterious errors saying `ClientError: Please provide a model_fn implementation.` I have implemented `model_fn` as you will see below.

The notebook looks like this:

```
from sagemaker.sklearn.estimator import SKLearnModel
from sagemaker import get_execution_role

role = get_execution_role()

estimator = SKLearnModel(
    entry_point='inference.py',
    source_dir='/home/ec2-user/SageMaker/my_path/src/',
    model_data='s3://my_bucket/my_key/output/model.tar.gz',
    role=role,
    py_version='py3'
)

predictor = estimator.deploy(
    instance_type='ml.m4.4xlarge',
    initial_instance_count=1,
    endpoint_name='my_endpoint'
)
```

And my `inference.py` looks like this:

```
import json

from pandas import DataFrame

from modelling.models import MyModel
from modelling.vectorisers import MyVectoriser
from util.config import TRAINING_VARIABLE_HEADERS


def model_fn(model_dir):
    return MyModel(inference_model_dir=model_dir)


def input_fn(request_body, request_content_type):
    input_dict = json.loads(request_body)
    print(f'Processing request {input_dict}')

    raw_input = DataFrame.from_dict(input_dict['media_items_data'])

    vectoriser = MyVectoriser()
    vectorised_input = vectoriser.transform(raw_input, TRAINING_VARIABLE_HEADERS)

    return {'inputs': vectorised_input}


def predict_fn(input_dict, model):
    prediction = model.predict(input_dict['inputs'])
    return prediction.tolist()


def output_fn(prediction, accept):
    return json.dumps(prediction)
```

The code folder structure is like this:

```
src
 L modelling 
   L models.py
   L vectorisers.py
 L utils
   L config.py
 inference.py
notebooks
 L train_deploy.ipynb
```

I've been though the documentation and can't figure out what I am doing wrong in this case. If anyone could help I would be very grateful.

I've tried playing around with the folder architecture, but to no avail.

Comment: Your code looks correct. As a sanity check, can you download the model tarball, unzip it and look at what's inside? 

You can find the S3 location of the model tarball through the SageMaker console or by describing the endpoint, then describing the endpoint configuration, then describing the model.

Comment: @PaytonStaub Thank you. The tarball contains my model file which I am able to open and instantiate fine.

Comment: The tarball should contain your `src` folder in addition to the model. The `deploy` function is what repacks your source directory alongside your model -- perhaps try re-running your notebook from start to finish to create a new model, endpoint, etc and see if the source code was repacked correctly into that tarball?

Comment: Yeah it has all the necessary files in. I figured out what my mistake was so will post in the answers later. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Tom111989 what was ur mistake? Running into same issue.

Comment: @Anonymous sorry I forgot to update this. My memory is hazy, but looking at PRs I think it was that train.py and inference.py were not both nested under the sources root - train.py was nested under another directory.